# GoBuffalo CSRF issue on production build

Tags: go, buffalo

When I run the application in development mode, I do not have this issue.

But when I build for production and run that binary and whenever I try to submit a form I get below error -

```
level=error time="2020-07-26T17:32:36+05:30" msg="CSRF token invalid" content_type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded duration="48.59µs" form="{\"ContactEmail\":[\"arunko350@gmail.com\"],\"ContactNumber\":[\"09738080932\"],\"Name\":[\"Arun Kolhapur\"],\"authenticity_token\":[\"N23TgN8v295iQwsNWCZySXCC2KFtv4CRkumqZ8jDIeXasV6iA10qaWl+RZ2SOxyg9JjjDzmpiIyPqH1c56eoBw==\"]}" human_size="0 B" method=POST params="{\"ContactEmail\":[\"arunko350@gmail.com\"],\"ContactNumber\":[\"09738080932\"],\"Name\":[\"Arun Kolhapur\"],\"authenticity_token\":[\"N23TgN8v295iQwsNWCZySXCC2KFtv4CRkumqZ8jDIeXasV6iA10qaWl+RZ2SOxyg9JjjDzmpiIyPqH1c56eoBw==\"]}" path=/organisations/ request_id=6922434a6f81d2c5891e-5a617ab03f631a1937f8 size=0 status=500
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you running production over HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: I am running on http.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this yesterday. I was running a Buffalo app in production, on HTTP. I found that the session cookies Buffalo was creating were marked `Secure`, so they weren't sent on non-HTTPS requests.

My solution was to get a Let's Encrypt HTTPS certificate and run my app in production mode over HTTPS.